# Maclaurin Series nth Derivative

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find $f^{(2016)}(0)$ if $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$.

From the Maclaurin series, 
$$\sin(x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comparing coefficient, $$\frac{f^{(j)}(0)}{j!}=\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}$$

Does it mean that if $j$ is not a multiple of $4n+2$, then the coefficient of $j$ term is $0$, consequently the $j$th derivative at that point is $0$?

So to find $f^{(2016)}(0)$ , $2016=4n+2$ implies that $n=503.5$, not an integer, so $f^{(2016)}(0)=0$?

Comment: You mean $f^{(2016)}(x)$ and not $f^{2016}(x)$ right ?

Comment: yes, the 2016th derivative, sorry for not stating clearly

Comment: @DaveClifford You are right.

Comment: Yes, your answer is zero as you guess.

Comment: @GEdgar is it because if $n$ is not an integer, then the factorial will become undefined? would you mind giving a full-length answer to explain it all?

Comment: The coefficient of $x^{2016}$ in that series is zero.  No need to mention "factorials" and whether they are "undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(a_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ be the coefficients, then
$$ f^{(j)}(0) = j! a_j
$$
$a_j$ is nonzero if $j = 4n + 2$ for some $n$, but that is not the case for $j = 2016$ since $2016 \equiv 0 \mod 4$, so $a_{2016} = 0$